# How did the F28 have such a good L/D ratio?

Tags: aircraft-design, lift, drag, efficiency, fokker-f28

The second link given on a Google search for "[Breguet Equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=breguet%20equation)" is to a [PDF document](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/Unified_Concepts/Breguet-Range-U2-notes-Fall08(2).pdf) from [MIT](http://www.mit.edu/).  On page 7 of this document is a chart showing [L/D ratios](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13762) for various commercial aircraft (turboprop, regional jet, and "large aircraft") plotted against the year the aircraft entered service.  Below is an image of this chart:

[image]

What appears to stand out (at the top of the chart) is the [Fokker F28](http://www.airliners.net/aircraft-data/fokker-f-28-fellowship/219) aircraft.

From an engineering and operational perspective, what enabled that aircraft to have such a high L/D ratio?

Also, I *thought* that the <strike>[F50](http://www.flyfokker.com/Fokker_50) /</strike> [F70](http://www.flyfokker.com/fokker_70) / [F100](http://www.flyfokker.com/fokker_100) aircraft had the F28's wing (or an evolutionary version).  Why didn't these aircraft have an equally good L/D ratio?

Comment: The [F 50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_50) is a development of the F-27 and has a different wing.

Comment: @PeterKämpf:  Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken as I am with the little Fokkers because I used to walk around the flight line and see them being built, I reckon that's a mistake. The F-28 having a better L/D ratio than the F-27 with its long slender wings doesn't sound right to me. The F100 with its supercritical wing definitely should have better L/D than F28.

The two entries for F-28 in figure 1.4 seem very similar to the entries in Figure 1.9 of the MIT document that you mention.

Comment: The supercritical wing only helps at higher Mach numbers, but the F 100 had a higher aspect ratio than the F-28, so I agree with your verdict. The low sweep angle helps in comparison with other jets, but not enough to make the graph look credible.

Comment: I agree with both Koyovis and Peter... The data look suspect.  Of course, the horizontal locations of aircraft are the same on both charts (x-axis is year of introduction in service).

Comment: Indeed. The y-values seem similar as well.

Comment: A little like comparing Vmin sink to Vbg, no?

Answer (score 8):

They just got this wrong. I have flown F28-1000 and -4000, the F100 and the B767-300. The most feet per nautical mile lost of these with idle power at any given Indicated Air Speed (say 270-280 below 25000 ft) is the F28-1000 (around 475 fpnm) then the F28-4000 at about 425 fpnm, then the F100 at about 350 fpnm and the best is the B767 at about 300-330.The 425 fpnm figure for the -4000 was measured by me around 2004 to get data for MS Flight Sim. All the rest are educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

There is one possible explanation in the analysis of the airfoil and the airspeed it is flown at.  A cambered wing, such as the Davis or the DAE-21, will produce superb lift to drag ratios, but at much lower airspeeds than supercritical wings fly at.

The Breuget Equation is as follows:

Range = Velocity × Lift/Drag x Specific Impulse × ln(W2/W1)

Specific Impulse is Thrust/fuel flow rate, Weight = Lift, Thrust = Drag, therefor:

Range = Velocity × Weight/fuel flow rate × ln(W2/W1).

The faster, heavier plane with the lowest fuel flow rate becomes "tops of the charts" in any year.  The graph, though interesting, seems to only point out the F-28 lifts more weight/drag at the speed it flies at per given unit of time, but not per given mile.  I would ask more of MIT.